# Global "ragged right" justification of report

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I don't want my report justified. I want it `\raggedright`.

I added a [\begin{raggedright} / \end{raggedright}](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Formatting) pair around the whole document, and it is working, but I'm wondering if I can somehow include the directive at the document level (without having to enclose the entire document like that! Feels awkward.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just add `\raggedright` after `\begin{document}`.

The idea behind using an environment limits the scope of `\raggedright`. However, if no scope is specified, it is set globally. If you want to keep things clean, you could add `\AtBeginDocument{\raggedright}` in your document preamble.

A slightly more advanced form of `\raggedright` is provided by the [`ragged2e` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e). It provides `\RaggedRight`, which allows some hyphenation.

Comment: I have always just added `\raggedright` in the *preamble*. Is there a reason not to?

Comment: That works as well in this case. I've always just added that kind of styling within the `document` environment. It may be that some document class (or package) issues a different justification `\AtBeginDocument`, which will override `\raggedright` if put in the *preamble*.