# ApA7 bibliography makes it nice without text wrapping

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, apa7

I am using Biblatex for APA7

`usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}`

`addbibresource{library.bib}`

I have noticed that my bibliography, as seen in the image, doesn't look as nice as I'd like it to and, in the worst case, might be incorrect.

In my opinion, nothing should be split in the middle. Please tell me if this is correct, and if not, how can I fix it?[image]

Comment: Are you referring to the urls getting split across two lines?  I think that looks nicer than getting pushed to the next line and having bad line breaks.  And what do you mean by "incorrect"?  That the href now points to the first part of the link and not the whole thing?  Have you verified that is the case?  Or are you referring to something completely different?

Comment: 1. Yes, URLs or DOIs are included. 2. Garcia, Ten-tative. 3. Grenn, [complete URL]. I am referring to these sources. By 'incorrect,' I mean whether they follow APA 7 guidelines (break lines), as I am trying to determine this. It's quite confusing and frustrating. Are break lines or or not

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot shows a bibliography typeset as justified text with hyphenation enabled. That means that TeX has a chance of making the line ends on the right meet up at the margin resulting in an even look. TeX achieves this by slightly increasing or decreasing the width of spaces between words and by breaking/hyphenating words that are too long.

Generally, I would not consider the question on whether or nor to use justification and hyphenation a question of the bibliography style. So it does not surprise me that `biblatex-apa` does not change anything in that regard and thus just follows your current document settings.

When it comes to entire papers, APA style says the following (https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/paper-format/paragraph-format)

> Align the text of an APA Style paper to the left margin. Leave the right margin uneven, or “ragged.” Do not use full justification for student papers or manuscripts being submitted for publication.
>
> Do not insert hyphens (manual breaks) in words at the end of line. However, it is acceptable if your word-processing program automatically inserts breaks in long hyperlinks ([such as in a DOI or URL in a reference list entry](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references)).

This would suggest that if you want to write your entire document in APA style (for manuscript submissions and student papers), you should indeed not justify your text and you should not even hyphenate anything (except URLs, which cannot avoid being broken if they are longer than a single line).

Personally, I find the look of "ragged-right" text without hyphenation with a reasonable text width pretty off-putting, so I recommend you double check with whoever you have to submit your work to what they prefer.

If you want to follow the ragged right requirement, you can use `\raggedright`  (see [Global "ragged right" justification of report](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33913/35864)). If you want to follow all aspects of APA style, you may want to look into using the `apa7` document class. It already takes care of using `\raggedright` (with the `student` and `man` options) and includes provisions for other APA formatting requirements as well.

Comment: You are my hero, not only for answering my question but also for thinking one step ahead and giving me the advice to talk to my supervisor. You are absolutely right. I need to ask my supervisor. For now, I've solved it using `raggedright` but whether he wants it that way or differently, he should decide. Just a quick explanation` , it's chaotic; on the one hand, we should use "apystel," on the other hand, we have a format with numbering, and the first heading is left-aligned. Nevertheless, thank you.

Comment: @Johannes Glad I could help. If the answer resolved your question, please consider [accepting it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking the little checkmark on the top left. That will mark the question as resolved and will signal to other people that you no longer require urgent help with this. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: Thanks you i wildo it =)